# Zooming to a clicked node on a D3 Force Directed Graph

Tags: javascript, d3.js, zooming, force-layout

I am trying to apply the van [Wijk Smooth Zooming example](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3828981) to a D3 force-directed graph I am working that already has the [drag+zoom](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/6123708) functioning on it. However, I don't know how to get my current position in order to make that the starting point of the transform. The I have the same issue with trying to use a normal transform.

I also tried looking at the [click-to-zoom-transform](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/2206590) but I wasn't sure how to apply that to a force-directed graph.

There are a couple things I want to apply it to, including being able to zoom and jump to a link's target node when I click on the link. Is there a way to get the current screen screen position so I could use it as a starting point to jump to where I want to go?

Comment: Assuming you have a "standard" force layout, the position of the target node would be `[d.target.x, d.target.y]`, where `d` is the data bound to the link.

Comment: Yes, I am using a "standard" force layout. I understand how to get the target x and y but to be able to transition to there, don't I have to know my current location? How do I get my current location on the map so I can jump from that to the target x and y?

Comment: How are you transitioning? If you just call `.transition().attr("transform", ...)` on the element, you don't need to know the current position.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I looked back at the way I was transitioning and figured it out. See my answer below.

Comment: for example [force-directed graph with click-node-to-zoom](https://bl.ocks.org/FrissAnalytics/f24a0abe38bd0b5290d56021b95f4381)

Answer (score 4):

Actually, I just figured it out based on the clicked function in [this example](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/9656675). My equation was wrong for my scale and translate numbers. I needed to get my translate numbers this way:

```
translate = [width / 2 - scale * x, height / 2 - scale * y]
```

Then I needed to call() the zoom behavior with the transition on the zoom behavior itself like below with the ".event" at the end to make it fire:

```
svg.transition().duration(750)
   .call(zoom.translate(translate).scale(scale).event);
```

and not doing it the wrong way by translating the svg like I was doing before:

```
svg.transition().duration(750)
   .attr("transform", translate(translate).scale(scale));
```