# Zoom in on a node in D3 force directed layout

Tags: javascript, d3.js, zooming, force-layout

I'm using a force directed layout, and I want to zoom in on a node when clicked. I looked at this [Zooming to a clicked node on a D3 Force Directed Graph](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25225069/zooming-to-a-clicked-node-on-a-d3-force-directed-graph) and it works for the most part. However, I have a problem where if the node is clicked when the graph hasn't stopped moving yet.

Is it recommended I change the tick function so it stops moving faster, or is there an easy way to lock in on a node?

Comment: You may be able to set the node to fixed (`d.fixed = true`) which should stop that node from moving. `force.stop()` might also be what you're looking for, which will stop the entire layout. Try setting these in your node click handler.